# SpringBoot 2 fails to bing ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've my properties like:

```
@Component
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("kafka")
public class KafkaProperties {

    @NotEmpty
    String broker;

    @NotEmpty
    String groupId;

    @NotEmpty
    String resetOffset = "latest";

    @NotEmpty
    String topic;

}
```

my application.properties like:

```
kafka.broker=localhost:9092
kafka.groupid=pdp-group
kafka.offset-reset=latest
kafka.topic=pdp-product-fragment
```

and the test is:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import({ReactiveKafkaConsumerTest.TestConfig.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class ReactiveKafkaConsumerTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    static final SharedKafkaTestResource sharedKafkaTestResource = new SharedKafkaTestResource();

    static class TestConfig extends KafkaConfig {

        Consumer<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> mockConsumer = mock(Consumer.class);

        @Override
        List<String> topics() {
            String topicName = Integer.toHexString(Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()));
            var kafkaTestUtils = sharedKafkaTestResource.getKafkaTestUtils();
            kafkaTestUtils.createTopic(topicName, 4, (short) 1);
            return asList(topicName);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> consumerProps() {
            Map<String, Object> props = super.consumerProps();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, sharedKafkaTestResource.getKafkaConnectString());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            return props;
        }

        @Override
        public Supplier<Consumer<ReceiverRecord<String, String>>> consumerSupplier() {
            return () -> mockConsumer;
        }


    }

    @Autowired
    List<String> topics;

    @Autowired
    TestConfig testConfig;

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void testReceiveMessages() {
        var kafkaTestUtils = sharedKafkaTestResource.getKafkaTestUtils();

        IntStream.range(0, 4)
                .forEach(i -> kafkaTestUtils.produceRecords(4, topics.get(0), i));


        ArgumentCaptor<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ReceiverRecord.class);
        verify(testConfig.mockConsumer, timeout(10000).times(16))
                .accept(captor.capture());

        var recordsPerPartition = captor.getAllValues().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.partition()));

        assertThat(recordsPerPartition.keySet(), containsInAnyOrder(0, 1, 2, 3));
        assertEquals(16, recordsPerPartition.values().stream().mapToInt(l -> l.size()).sum());
    }

}
```

It fails with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.validation.BindValidationException: Binding validation errors on kafka
   - Field error in object 'kafka' on field 'broker': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.kafka.broker,NotEmpty.broker,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [kafka.broker,broker]; arguments []; default message [broker]]; default message [must not be empty]
   - Field error in object 'kafka' on field 'topic': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.kafka.topic,NotEmpty.topic,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [kafka.topic,topic]; arguments []; default message [topic]]; default message [must not be empty]
   - Field error in object 'kafka' on field 'groupId': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.kafka.groupId,NotEmpty.groupId,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [kafka.groupId,groupId]; arguments []; default message [groupId]]; default message [must not be empty]
```

I've tried many things like:

- Adding SpringBootTest Replacing PropertySource with
- TestPropertySource

Spring boot version is: 2.2.2.RELEASE

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Binding properties or yaml files to POJO is spring boot feature [Loading YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml), so if you want to use that during test you need to load test application context using @SpringBootTest. And also i would recommend to use 
@Configuration with @Configurationproperties. see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) for more information

> Note: If we don't use @Configuration in the POJO, then we need to add @EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class) in the main Spring application class to bind the properties into the POJO: